# MagicDraw - show Interface with true UML notation

Tags: interface, uml, tool-uml, magic-draw

I can't find a way (searching through MagicDraw and its doc as well as Goolge) to make MagicDraw show an Interface as it is defined in UML with the stereotype notation << interface >> instead of just coloring it green and drawing a circle in the right corner.

Could someone give me a hint on how to display interfaces like that in MagicDraw please.

PS: does MagicDraw 16.8 have a default way how to draw .Net (C#) properties?

Comment: in case I made it not clear - the <<interface>> should be shown in the diagram under the name of the interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a very old question, but in case anyone else wants to know the answer (as it was my case when I arrived to this post):

1. In the Containment window, right-click on the Data folder and select New Element -> Stereotype.
2. In the new element << >> that appears under the Data folder, rename it Interface.
3. In the main UML window, right-click on your own interface symbol and select Stereotype -> Interface [Element] (this last item in the Stereotype list appears when you create it following the steps above).

This was tested in MagicDraw version 16.

Comment: ok it was not really important to me anymore but still nice to have an answer - thanks

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to right click the interface symbol and change "symbol properties"/show sterotypes as: text. It might actually be necessary to create the sterotype "interface". I tried this out in Magicdraw 17.0 and it does not work as expected. A bug report to NoMagic might be in order.